# drupal ajax login return user id

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm making an ajax module for drupal 6 in regards to user login.

I need to

1. disable redirect on the user login form (I know I need to do a form alter on this form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login/6 but what and how?)
2. get back a json response containing the success/fail and the user's UID.

Any idea how I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with [ajax_register module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_register) or [ajax module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax) and customize it.

Or you [create your own module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) for that purpose. You'd have to implement [hook_form_user_login_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6), alter the form as needed, [add some Javascript](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) and write a callback function that calls `user_login_submit()` and sends a JSON response.

I strongly recommend to use an existing module. There might be more than the two mentioned above. Try searching for "drupal login ajax".

Comment: What do I need to change with hook form alter? IE. what's the command for disabling redirect? Also how do I send a JSON response. That was the question. I have looked at a bunch of the existing ajax modules, they generally don't contain the code that I'm looking for. I think the ajax module does, but it's complex enough that I don't really understand what I'm looking at/for. Please help.